# what is the ClientID of action project

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have recently started working on the Dialogflow and I found something like this

`const app = dialogflow({
  // REPLACE THE PLACEHOLDER WITH THE CLIENT_ID OF YOUR ACTIONS PROJECT
  clientId: "********************67780",
});`

what is this clientID means?

Comment: Where did you find this? It is difficult to answer your question without knowing what library you're trying to use, what you're trying to do, and if you're getting any errors with it. Please update your question with as much information as you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

- Login to your Actions Console :  [Actions on Google Console](https://console.actions.google.com/)
- From the top navigation menu under Develop > Account linking (left nav):

  - Account creation > select Yes, allow users to sign up for new
    accounts via voice
  - Linking type > select Google Sign In.
  - Client information > copy Client ID > Save.

Reference: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-google-sign-in-java/blob/master/README.md